# Youtube upload widget time

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

It's possible do a capture webcam video w/ useful Youtube Upload Widget in a limited time (e.g. 3 mins) and after upload this video?

Thank you!This is my code:

```
    <script>
      // 2. Asynchronously load the Upload Widget and Player API code.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. Define global variables for the widget and the player.
      //    The function loads the widget after the JavaScript code
      //    has downloaded and defines event handlers for callback
      //    notifications related to the widget.
      var widget;
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
          width: 500,
          events: {
            'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
            'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. This function is called when a video has been successfully uploaded.
      function onUploadSuccess(event) {
        alert('Video ID ' + event.data.videoId + ' was uploaded and is currently being processed.');
      }

      // 5. This function is called when a video has been successfully
      //    processed.
      function onProcessingComplete(event) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: 390,
          width: 640,
          videoId: event.data.videoId,
          events: {}
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example I check video length after video processing by sending ajax request.

```
     function onProcessingComplete(event) {
            $.ajax({
            url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+event.data.videoId+'?v=2&alt=json',
            success:function(data){
                var sec = data['entry']['media$group']['yt$duration']['seconds'];
                if(sec < 60){
                    var errorText = "Video must be long at least 1 min";
                    showError(errorText);
                }else{
//OK                    
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                showError("Failed to make request.");
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```